# Not able to get expected result value in table in oracle (Negative record rows)

Tags: oracle

[Based on values in CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM column, find out the match of CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM column values with CLCL_ID column values of same table. If matching exist, insert additional row of the entire matched row but with negative value in PAID_AMT & CALC columns. The row which is inserted newly should have CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO value which I mentioned in pic. I have added my code in comment also..I got stuck in between..This is the query I have used

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (CLCL_ID VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL, PAID_AMT NUMBER, CALC NUMBER, SEQ_NO VARCHAR(12), CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO VARCHAR2(12), CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM VARCHAR2(12), CLCL_PAID_DT TIMESTAMP(3), INSRT_DT TIMESTAMP(3));

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (‘21GMA0049600’, 63, 81, ‘1’, ‘ ‘, ‘ ‘, TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-22 05:03:19.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’), TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-22 05:03:19.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (‘21GMA0049501’, 41, 53, ‘1’, ‘ ‘, ‘21GMA0049600‘, TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-29 05:12:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’), TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-27 05:03:19.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));


CREATE TABLE TABLE_DUMMY (CLCL_ID VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL, CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO VARCHAR2(12), CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM VARCHAR2(12), CLCL_PAID_DT TIMESTAMP(3), INSRT_DT TIMESTAMP(3) );

INSERT INTO TABLE_DUMMY VALUES (‘21GMA0049600’, ‘ ‘, ‘ ‘, TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-22 05:03:19.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’), TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-22 05:03:19.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));

INSERT INTO TABLE_DUMMY VALUES (‘21GMA0049501’,  ‘ ‘, ‘21GMA0049600‘, TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-29 05:12:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’), TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-01-27 05:03:19.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));
```

To insert the record with negative values in PAID_AMT and CALC columns, I have written a query like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
 SELECT CLCL_ID, -1*PAID_AMT, -1*CALC, SEQ_NO, CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO, CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM, CLCL_PAID_DT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT T1.CLCL_ID, T1.PAID_AMT, T1.CALC, T1.SEQ_NO, DY.CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO, T1.CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM, T2.CLCL_PAID_DT, T1.INSRT_DT
 FROM TABLE_DUMMY DY JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON DY.CLCL_ID = T1.CLCL_ID
                      JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.CLCL_ID = T2.CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM
 ) T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 TT
       WHERE T.CLCL_ID = TT.CLCL_ID
             AND TT.PAID_AMT = -1 * T.PAID_AMT
    );
```

After running this query for multiple times, it shouldn't insert existing records. This works fine but it is not populating the value in CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO of negative record row..Can someone look into this][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUTTo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the value of `T2.CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM` into `CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO` while doing insertion as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
 SELECT CLCL_ID, -1*PAID_AMT, -1*CALC, SEQ_NO, CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM, CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO, CLCL_PAID_DT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT T1.CLCL_ID, T1.PAID_AMT, T1.CALC, T1.SEQ_NO, DY.CLCL_ID_ADJ_TO, T2.CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM, T2.CLCL_PAID_DT, T1.INSRT_DT
 FROM TABLE_DUMMY DY JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON DY.CLCL_ID = T1.CLCL_ID
                      JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.CLCL_ID = T2.CLCL_ID_ADJ_FROM
 ) T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 TT
       WHERE T.CLCL_ID = TT.CLCL_ID
             AND TT.PAID_AMT = -1 * T.PAID_AMT
    );
```

Also, Your query is not inserting multiple records if it is executed multiple times.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=255bbd1ad440fb97406f14df9dc6ede2)